# Labelling Openshift Build transient pods

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-3

I have a simple S2I build running on an Openshift 3.11 project that outputs to an Image Stream.

The build is working fine, the resulting images are tagged correctly and available in the stream. My issue is, each build spins up a transient pod to handle doing the actual build. I would like to label these pods. This project is shared between multiple teams and we have several scripts that differentiate pods based on a  label.

Right now each one automatically gets labelled like so:

```
openshift.io/build.name: <buildname>-<buildnum>
```

Which is fine, I don't want to get rid of that label. I just want to add an additional custom label (something like `owner: <teamname>`). How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can add your custom label using `imageLabels` section in the `buildConfig` as follows. Further information is here, [Output Image Labels](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_output.html#output-image-labels).

```
spec:
  output:
    to:
      kind: "ImageStreamTag"
      name: "your-image:latest"
    imageLabels:
    - name: "owner"
      value: "yourteamname"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's close but I don't want to add a Docker Image label to the produced image, I want to add an Openshift Pod label to the transient pod that get's created when I kick off the build.